# Memory leak and initialisation

Tags: variables, memory-leaks, scope, initialization

How are memory leaks related to initialization? Some sources tell that proper initialization of variables helps in preventing and detecting memory leaks while some others tell that both are not related. Could someone tell the exact answer with reason?
Source :https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223862/how-important-is-to-initialize-a-variable

Comment: Can you provide the source you have seen?

Comment: @LearningMathematics please find the link above.(first and third answers in the link.)